# In Hibernate Criteria, can I change the operator of disjunction?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Can I change the default operator of disjunction in Hibernate Criteria?

usage:

```
disjunction.add(Criterion1);
disjunction.add(Criterion2);
disjunction.add(Criterion3);
```

I want to set 'and' operator !

Comment: sorry for disturbing , now i found conjunction for my usage !

Comment: You can answer your own question and even get votes for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found conjunction for my usage!

Group expressions together in a single conjunction (Criterion1 and Criterion2 and Criterion3...).

used conjunction as follow:

```
conjunction.add(Criterion1);
conjunction.add(Criterion2);
conjunction.add(Criterion3);
```